# Bullet points to small with ::before / I tried :display none and use ::marker but wont work with my theme

Tags: css, list, html-lists

my bullet points are too small and I can't seem to find a fix for this.

If I adjust the font-size to make the bullet point bigger, the ::before item gets vertically higher which creates a gap and pushes the following paragraph further away/down.

Website: https://bloglized.com/

CSS: attached are two images down below for more details (default + adjusted)

[default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IO6aB.jpg)
[adjusted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQXZy.jpg)

If someone knows how to fix this, I would appreciate it.

EDIT: Also, I would like to use the list-style-position: outside, to vertically align my text. Unfortunately, it seems like it's not possible here. If anyone knows a fix for that as well that would be awesome!

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) CSS property.

After you've made your `font-size` adjustments, change your `line-height` as desired.

Comment: awesome that helped me. thank you! :-)

Do you also know a fix for the list-style-position: outside to vertically align the text / to get the bullet point out, by any chance?

Comment: @Bodo Use negative margin on the containing list element. E.g. `ul { margin-left: -32px; }`. Experiment with margin and see what works for your `font-size`. As an aside, if my answers fulfilled your questions needs, please mark my answer as the accepted answer.